# How to define '=' for own class?

Tags: vb.net

I created a class like this:

```
 Public Class WorkDay            

    <JsonProperty("start")>
    Public Property starttime As String = Nothing
    <JsonProperty("end")>
    Public Property endtime As String = Nothing
    Public Property breaks As New List(Of Break)

End Class
```

Now I need to compare an object of this class, for example this:

```
Dim working_plan = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, WorkDay))(wp)
Dim DayNames = {"monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"}
Dim this_day = working_plan(day)

If this_day = Nothing Then
   ...
```

Now `this_day` is an object of `WorkDay` class, so when I try to compare to nothing, I get:

> The operator = is not defined for `WorkDay` types.

I should define the operator in my own class? How I can do that?

Comment: Bad idea! If you want override `=` operator only for comparing against `Nothing` then use `Is Nothing` or `IsNot Nothing`. @Alex's answer contains this, but I want to mentioned that overriding in this case doesnät seems good approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: Edit says that I should read the question carefully before answering questions ;)
To check whether an object is Nothing you have to use the `Is` repsective `IsNot` key words:

```
    If this_day Is Nothing Then
```

Respective:

```
   If this_day IsNot Nothing Then
```

---

Original answer of comparing objects which are not nothing:

Overload the equal operator in your WorkDay class:

```
Public Shared Operator =(x As WorkDay, y As WorkDay)
       'Code to determine whetther x equals y
End Operator
```

Be aware that you also have to overload the not equals operator:

```
Public Shared Operator <>(x As WorkDay, y As WorkDay)
      'Code to determine whetther x not equals y
End Operator
```

---

In resepect of Magnus comment:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
    Dim o As WorkDay = TryCast(obj, WorkDay)
    If o IsNot Nothing Then
        'check whether o equals Me
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    'return a feasible hashcode of a member of Me e.g.
     Return Me.StartTime.GetHashCode() XOR Me.EndTime.GetHashCode() 
End Function
```

Comment: I didn't know this practice, thanks :) Anyway, when I insert this function I get for both the function: the operator = does not return any value for all code paths

Comment: About @Magnus comment: overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is **mandatory** in this case.

Comment: Incomplete and in the OP's case needless part about overriding operator. OP's question was clearly "xy" problem, where "y" was perfectly noticeable

Comment: @Dillinger you have to put in concrete code where I just put comments. Which attributes define if 2 of your WorkDay objects are equal/unequal?